# Fortify - How to scan particular builds of a maven project?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, fortify

We are performing source code review on one of our customer's code. The project uses Maven. The project as a whole contains around 1000 modules.

Let's assume that the Project's name is `Project X`, the modules within `Project X` are sequentially named, `Module 1`, `Module 2`, and so on until `Module 1000`.

If I want to scan the whole project, I just go into `Project X's` directory and run `mvn sca:translate` and `mvn sca:scan` and the whole project is scanned.
If I want to scan only `Module 1`, I go into `Module 1's` directory and run the commands and `Module 1` is scanned.

My question is if its possible to scan only a group of modules, say `Module 1`, `Module 2`, and so on until `Module 100` with minimal configurations and human efforts? We do not want to scan the whole project, we only want to scan a bunch of modules.

Below is an approximate directory structure of the project.

```html
Project X              
|                      
+-------->Module 1     
|         +            
|         +----src     
|         |            
|         +----test    
|         |            
|         +----pom.xml 
|                      
|                      
+-------->Module 2     
|         |            
|         +----+src    
|         |            
|         +----+test   
|         |            
|         +----+pom.xml
|                                           
+--------->pom.xml     
+
```

PS: We are using `Fortify Maven Plugin` for scanning.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the maven translate commands to the same Fortify build ID and then scan that build ID. Such as:

```
cd module 1
sourceanalyzer -b mybuild mvn sca:translate
cd to module2
sourceanalyzer -b mybuild mvn sca:translate
sourceanalyzer -b mybuild -scan -f output.fpr
```

What that does it take the translated code from module 1 and then the translated code from module 2 and puts them in one Fortify build ID called mybuild. You then run a scan against the "mybuild" build ID and it will give you a scan of the code in module 1 and module 2.

You can also try posting Fortify issues to their online forum at https://protect724.hp.com. The support group monitors those forums.